# iTunes Connect Submit current Pre-Release Version Number

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to understand how iTunes Connect works for taking my current latest Prelease build and submitting that for the first time in the App Store.

I want to release my App as 1.0.0 however when I first archived and submitted the Prelease I didn't realize the version in Xcode mattered and was 1.0.0, so now I've just incrementally been versioning my beta builds and am currently at 1.3.2

[image]

What will happen if I submit Build 1.3.2 as it's first release as "iTunes build 1.0.0" (see screenshot below)? What will that mean for my Xcode versioning/prelease at that point?

At this point what I'd like to do is clear out all the current Prerelease builds and upload fresh from 1.0.0, then just submit that. What are my options?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can not submit the same app with a previously used version number. iTunes won't let you save changes with 1.0.0 .

If you want to release a build with version 1.0.0 you have to create a new app id with a different bundle identifier. But then, users who previously downloaded your app won't get it as an update. It counts as a different app.

However, If you try to do this with previous app is already in app store, your app might get rejected from app review team.

Comment: Thanks.. so clearly creating a new app id and bundle identifier is out.. so does this mean I need to release it to the App Store as build 1.3.2? Does the "Version" number in my image above need to match the build selected? Apple sure does a solid job making this confusing!

Comment: Yes, version number must match the build version. Btw when you uploading many builds for the same version (just like in your 1st image with 3 uploaded builds) , you can use the same version number with a different build number instead of increasing the version number. Eg:- 1.3.2(1.0) , 1.3.2 (1.1) etc. Anyways whenever you release a new version to app store you have to increase the version.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why the version in the second image is even necessary? Can't they detect the version number from the already uploaded prelease version that I'm submitting? Thanks for your insight btw!